# Pick phone_number attribute On Button Click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-6

I have an index file as shown below that is Picking information from the DB and displays a list.

I want to be able to pick the phone_number of when the User has clicks the Contact button so as to send an SMS to that phone number.

```
<div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen bg-white">
  <div class="max-w-4xl flex items-center h-auto lg:h-screen flex-wrap mx-auto my-32 lg:my-0">
    <% @providers.each do |provider| %>
      <!--Main Col-->
      <div id="profile" class="w-full lg:w-3/5 rounded-lg lg:rounded-l-lg lg:rounded-r-none shadow-2xl bg-white opacity-75 mx-6 lg:mx-0">
        <div class="p-4 md:p-12 text-center lg:text-left">
          <!-- Image for mobile view-->
          <div class="block lg:hidden rounded-full shadow-xl mx-auto -mt-16 h-48 w-48 bg-cover bg-center" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/MP0IUfwrn0A')"></div>
          <%= image_tag provider.avatar.variant(resize_to_limit: [150, nil]), class: "w-100 h-100 rounded-full" %>
          <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold pt-8 lg:pt-0"><%= provider.full_name %></h1>
          <div class="mx-auto lg:mx-0 w-4/5 pt-3 border-b-2 border-teal-500 opacity-25"></div>
          <p class="invisible">
            <p>Services:</p>
            <% provider.service.each do |s| %>
              <p class="pt-4 text-base font-bold flex items-center justify-center lg:justify-start">
                <%= s %>
              </p>
            <% end %>
          </p>
          <p class="pt-2 text-gray-600 text-xs lg:text-sm flex items-center justify-center lg:justify-start">

            <%= provider.zip_code %></p>
          <p class="pt-8 text-sm"><%= provider.brief_description %></p>
          <!-- <p><%= provider.phone_number %></p> -->
          <div class="pt-12 pb-8">
            <%= button_tag "Contact", class: "bg-teal-700 hover:bg-teal-900 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full"%>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <!-- Pin to top right corner -->
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the result of the code above:

[image]

I have experimented with JS with the code below, but I am only picking the phone_number of one of the items and it appears for all the rest when I click the submit button.

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
   <% @providers.each do |p|%>
      window.providerPhone = '<%= j p.phone_number %>';
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
  <div class="pt-12 pb-8">
    <%= button_tag "Contact", class: "bg-teal-700 hover:bg-teal-900 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full", :onclick => "alert(providerPhone)" %> 
  </div>
```

I figure that I have to utilize JS but I am not certain on how to go about it.
I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864798/sending-an-email-notification-on-button-click/15868810) but it wasn't helpful.
How can I go about solving this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to wrap an `<a> tag` around the button like so;

```
<div class="pt-12 pb-8">
  <a href="<%= providers_notify_path(provider_phone: provider.phone_number, provider_serv: provider.service)%>">
     <%= button_tag "Contact", class: "bg-teal-700 hover:bg-teal-900 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full"%>
   </a>
</div>
```

I just included a path in the `<a> tag` with an `href`. 
The path I used is: `providers_notify_path`.
Then I passed the values I wanted to acces in another controller within the path.
In this case I picked the `provider_phone` from `provider.phone_number`.

So, to use the `provider_phone` value in the controller, I did this:

```
@provider_phone = params[:provider_phone]
```

Then I could use the instance variable `@provider_phone` in the action I wanted which in particular case was the `create` action.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [`each_with_index`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index) like so:

```rb
<%= javascript_tag do %>
   <% @providers.each_with_index do |p, index|%>
      window.providerPhone = '<%= j p[index].phone_number %>';
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
  <div class="pt-12 pb-8">
    <%= button_tag "Contact", class: "bg-teal-700 hover:bg-teal-900 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full", :onclick => "alert(providerPhone)" %> 
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the response!
With this implementation I get an error `undefined method `phone_number' for nil:NilClass` 
However, I did a different approach that has worked for me.